# Inserting variables into .html.slim file that are declared from a different directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, variables, require, slim-lang

I am new to Ruby. I have a .html.slim file that has some numerical values that I want to replace with variables declared in another .rb file. I have this rough setup:

```
company/app/views/landing_pages_hello/_hello.html.slim
company/lib/random/variables.rb
```

**company/lib/random/variables.rb**

```
class A
  MY_SALARY = 5000
end
```

**company/app/views/landing_pages_hello/_hello.html.slim**

```
table
  tbody
    tr
      td
        = ...
        title=("My salary is $5000")
```

So I am wondering how do I replace the "5000" in the `_hello.html.slim` file with the variable `MY_SALARY` from the `variables.rb` file.

Answer (score 1):

The [Getting Started with Rails](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) guide explains how to pass variables from a **controller** to a **view**. I'd recommend reading most of that guide now. There are other guides you'll want to read later as you learn more.

The [Slim documentation](http://slim-lang.com/) explains how to use variables in your views.

Comment: I would probally skip Slim for the time being and learn ERB. It will make it easier to follow 99% of the Rails tutorials.